# How to find all the possible words using adjacent letters in a matrix

Tags: c#, recursion, matrix

I have the following test matrix:

```
a l i
g t m
j e a
```

*I intend to create an algorithm that helps me find every possible word from a given minimum length to a maximum length using adjacent letters only.*

For example:

Minimum: 3 letters

Maximum: 6 letters

Based on the test matrix, I should have the following results:

- ali
- alm
- alg
- alt
- ati
- atm
- atg
- ...
- atmea

etc.

I created a test code (C#) that has a custom class which represents the letters.

Each letter knows its neighbors and has a generation counter (for keeping track of them during traversal).

Here is its code:

```
public class Letter
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public char Character { get; set; }

    public List<Letter> Neighbors { get; set; }

    public Letter PreviousLetter { get; set; }

    public int Generation { get; set; }

    public Letter(char character)
    {
        Neighbors = new List<Letter>();
        Character = character;
    }

    public void SetGeneration(int generation)
    {
        foreach (var item in Neighbors)
        {
            item.Generation = generation;
        }
    }
}
```

I figured out that if I want it to be dynamic, it has to be based on recursion.

Unfortunately, the following code creates the first 4 words, then stops. It is no wonder, as the recursion is stopped by the specified generation level.

The main problem is that the recursion returns only one level but it would be better to return to the starting point.

```
 private static void GenerateWords(Letter input, int maxLength, StringBuilder sb)
    {
        if (input.Generation >= maxLength)
        {               
            if (sb.Length == maxLength)
            {
                allWords.Add(sb.ToString());
                sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
            }                
            return;
        }
        sb.Append(input.Character);
        if (input.Neighbors.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var child in input.Neighbors)
            {
                if (input.PreviousLetter == child)
                    continue;
                child.PreviousLetter = input;
                child.Generation = input.Generation + 1;
                GenerateWords(child, maxLength, sb);
            }
        }
    }
```

So, I feel a little stuck, any idea how I should proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here, you can treat this as a graph traversal problem.  You start at each given letter, finding each path of length **min_size** to **max_size**, with 3 and 6 as those values in your example.  I suggest a recursive routine that builds the words as paths through the grid.  This will look something like the following; replace types and pseudo-code with your preferences.

```
<array_of_string> build_word(size, current_node) {
    if (size == 1)  return current_node.letter as an array_of_string;
    result = <empty array_of_string>
    for each next_node in current_node.neighbours {
        solution_list = build_word(size-1, next_node);
        for each word in solution_list {
             // add current_node.letter to front of that word.
             // add this new word to the result array
        }
    }
    return the result array_of_string
}
```

Does that move you toward a solution?

Comment: Well, it does more than moving forward :) Actually, you presented a working solution... I added some checking (not to use the same letter, don't check neighbor parent etc.), but it works now. I think, I should go back to school to learn some algorithm theory again... Thanks for guiding me :)

Answer (score 1):

When solving these kind of problems, I tend to use immutable classes because everything is so much easier to reason about. The following implementation makes use of a *ad hoc* `ImmutableStack` because its pretty straightforward to implement one. In production code I'd probably want to look into `System.Collections.Immutable` to improve performance (`visited` would be an `ImmutableHashSet<>` to point out the obvious case).

So why do I need an immutable stack? To keep track of the current character path and visited "locations" inside the matrix. Because the selected tool for the job is immutable, sending it down recursive calls is a no brainer, we know it can't change so I don't have to worry about my invariants in every recursion level.

So lets implement an immutable stack.

We'll also implement a helper class `Coordinates` that encapsulates our "locations" inside the matrix, will give us value equality semantics and a convenient way to obtain valid neighbors of any given location. It will obviously come in handy.

```
public class ImmutableStack<T>: IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly T head;
    private readonly ImmutableStack<T> tail;

    public static readonly ImmutableStack<T> Empty = new ImmutableStack<T>(default(T), null);
    public int Count => this == Empty ? 0 : tail.Count + 1;

    private ImmutableStack(T head, ImmutableStack<T> tail)
    {
        this.head = head;
        this.tail = tail;
    }

    public T Peek()
    {
        if (this == Empty)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Can not peek an empty stack.");

        return head;
    }

    public ImmutableStack<T> Pop()
    {
        if (this == Empty)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Can not pop an empty stack.");

        return tail;
    }

    public ImmutableStack<T> Push(T value) => new ImmutableStack<T>(value, this);

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var current = this;

        while (current != Empty)
        {
            yield return current.head;
            current = current.tail;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}

struct Coordinates: IEquatable<Coordinates>
{
    public int Row { get; }
    public int Column { get; }

    public Coordinates(int row, int column)
    {
        Row = row;
        Column = column;
    }

    public bool Equals(Coordinates other) => Column == other.Column && Row == other.Row;
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Coordinates)
        {
            return Equals((Coordinates)obj);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() => unchecked(27947 ^ Row ^ Column);

    public IEnumerable<Coordinates> GetNeighbors(int rows, int columns)
    {
        var increasedRow = Row + 1;
        var decreasedRow = Row - 1;
        var increasedColumn = Column + 1;
        var decreasedColumn = Column - 1;
        var canIncreaseRow = increasedRow < rows;
        var canIncreaseColumn = increasedColumn < columns;
        var canDecreaseRow = decreasedRow > -1;
        var canDecreaseColumn = decreasedColumn > -1;

        if (canDecreaseRow)
        {
            if (canDecreaseColumn)
            {
                yield return new Coordinates(decreasedRow, decreasedColumn);
            }

            yield return new Coordinates(decreasedRow, Column);

            if (canIncreaseColumn)
            {
                yield return new Coordinates(decreasedRow, increasedColumn);
            }
        }

        if (canIncreaseRow)
        {
            if (canDecreaseColumn)
            {
                yield return new Coordinates(increasedRow, decreasedColumn);
            }

            yield return new Coordinates(increasedRow, Column);

            if (canIncreaseColumn)
            {
                yield return new Coordinates(increasedRow, increasedColumn);
            }
        }

        if (canDecreaseColumn)
        {
            yield return new Coordinates(Row, decreasedColumn);
        }

        if (canIncreaseColumn)
        {
            yield return new Coordinates(Row, increasedColumn);
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, now we need a method that traverses the matrix visiting each position once returning words that have a specified minimum number of characters and don't exceed a specified maximum.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetWords(char[,] matrix,
                                           Coordinates startingPoint,
                                           int minimumLength,
                                           int maximumLength)
```

That looks about right. Now, when recursing we need to keep track of what characters we've visited, That's easy using our immutable stack, so our recursive method will look like:

```
static IEnumerable<string> getWords(char[,] matrix,
                                    ImmutableStack<char> path,
                                    ImmutableStack<Coordinates> visited,
                                    Coordinates coordinates,
                                    int minimumLength,
                                    int maximumLength)
```

Now the rest is just plumbing and connecting the wires:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetWords(char[,] matrix,
                                           Coordinates startingPoint,
                                           int minimumLength,
                                           int maximumLength)
    => getWords(matrix,
                ImmutableStack<char>.Empty,
                ImmutableStack<Coordinates>.Empty,
                startingPoint,
                minimumLength,
                maximumLength);


static IEnumerable<string> getWords(char[,] matrix,
                                    ImmutableStack<char> path,
                                    ImmutableStack<Coordinates> visited,
                                    Coordinates coordinates,
                                    int minimumLength,
                                    int maximumLength)
{
    var newPath = path.Push(matrix[coordinates.Row, coordinates.Column]);
    var newVisited = visited.Push(coordinates);

    if (newPath.Count > maximumLength)
    {
        yield break;
    }
    else if (newPath.Count >= minimumLength)
    {
        yield return new string(newPath.Reverse().ToArray());
    }

    foreach (Coordinates neighbor in coordinates.GetNeighbors(matrix.GetLength(0), matrix.GetLength(1)))
    {
        if (!visited.Contains(neighbor))
        {
            foreach (var word in getWords(matrix,
                                          newPath,
                                          newVisited,
                                          neighbor,
                                          minimumLength,
                                          maximumLength))
            {
                yield return word;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And we're done. Is this the most elegant or fastest algorithm? Probably not, but I find it the most understandable and therefore maintainable. Hope it helps you out.

*UPDATE* Based upon comments below, I've run a few test cases one of which is:

```
var matrix = new[,] { {'a', 'l'},
                      {'g', 't'} };
var words = GetWords(matrix, new Coordinates(0,0), 2, 4);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, words.Select((w,i) => $"{i:00}: {w}")));
```

And the outcome is the expected:

```
00: ag
01: agl
02: aglt
03: agt
04: agtl
05: at
06: atl
07: atlg
08: atg
09: atgl
10: al
11: alg
12: algt
13: alt
14: altg
```

Comment: Thanks, it a quite a solution. I tested it with the same parameters and your solution creates a significantly larger number of possible words (Prune's algorithm creates _600k words_ for a min(3) and max(12) in a _4x4 matrix_, yours creates over _5.5m words_). Because of this, your algorithm takes cca. 30 seconds to run, Prune's takes 2-3. I didn't check yet, which is closer to reality :)

Comment: @nestor duplicate words might be one reason, in not checking if any given words has already been produced. Run the algorithm with a much smaller solution set and see where the difference is. To be honest I haven't tested my solution so it could be buggy.

Comment: @Nestor: "Prune's algorithm" is hardly the proper name.  This is a well-known solution in recursive programming, multiple recursion with accrual of results.  The base is DIjkstra's algorithm for graph traversal; I just adapted it for the requirement of length, rather than a given final state.  You can find the accrual logic in many answers tagged "recursion" on this site, especially "target sum" and "making change" problems.

Comment: @Prune Thanks for the explanation (I didn't even know the term 'accrual', though my native is not English :). I really like it, I find it simple but needed the help.

Comment: @nestor Ok, had time to run a few small test cases and my implementation seems to be working well. Not sure why you are getting such different results but I don't have your implementation bases on Prune's solution so its kind of hard to diagnose.

Comment: @Nestor Cant test it, I'd need to know how you build your `Letter` graph from the input matrix. You haven't provided that code.

Comment: @nestor Sorry thats still not it. You've just added a random matrix generator and the construction of a disconnected letter graph; where are you setting the neighbors for each letter? But never mind, just run the case I've added to my answer and see if you get the same results. Running cases where the output is thousands of words is pointless, how are you going to even begin to know if your solution is working correctly? Run much smaller cases where you can solve the output in your head or with pencil and paper and compare the results.